# Is "I am running" or "I run" grammatical to say while running?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, continuous-aspect, present-continuous

Please check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXuPfVRQbxc).

I understood *for performative verbs, if we are doing something and, at the same time, we are saying it, we don't need to use the present continuous tense*. I am not sure I have it right.

For example, when I say, "*I promise to do my homework*," I am making the promise as I say this.

However, "**promise**" is not a stative verb, so we could say, "*He is promising to do his homework.*"

[Some sites](http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2012/10/stative-verbs-plus.html) say these are performative verbs, e.g. accept, acknowledge, advise, apologise, and warn, etc.

[This site](https://poligo.com/en/articles/grammar/performative-verbs-when-you-say-word-you-do-action-word-describes) says,

> Performative verbs: when you say a word you do the action the word
> describes
>
> There is a group of verbs called "performative verbs". When you say
> these words, you actually do the action of the verb. If I say, "I
> apologise", by saying "apologise", I make my apology.
>
> Compare this to a word like "run". If I say, "I run in the morning",
> then "run" just represents an action. Actually running is a different
> action. I cannot run just by saying "run".

What if I was running and saying, "**I run**," at the same time?

## My Question

Does the **performative principle** apply to other verbs, such as "run" or "eat"?

Would the utterance, "**I run**," be grammatical if I was running while saying it?

Comment: It's grammatical anyway. 'I run, you run, he runs, we run, you run, they run'.

Comment: There's a grave misconception here. A 'performative verb' is one where the actual utterance of the verb accomplishes the stated end. "**Performative verbs** name actions that are performed, wholly or partly, by saying something (state, promise); **non-performative verbs** name other types of actions, types of action which are independent of speech (walk, sleep **[, run]**)."
-Kirsten Malmkjaer, "Speech-Act Theory." The Linguistics Encyclopedia, 2nd ed. Routledge, 2004 [[Nordquist; ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/performative-verb-1691606)]

Comment: A grey area must arise when the utterers' (plural intended) _ability to deliver_ is in doubt. Moses in the Old Testament was commanded (on the second occasion water seemed a distant dream) to speak to [unusual construction; Living Bible probably uses 'tell' or 'command']  _the Rock_ to gush forth water; he could have achieved this, but probably none of the other Israelites could have done so.  So, as conforms with the usual pattern, 'performative verbal usages' rather than 'performative verbs' would seem to make sense. _I won't go into 'magic' and squibs._

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **when** you say a word, you do the action the word describes

This is correct but insufficient: *when* suggests that the only requirement is that the saying and the action occur at the same time, irrespective of causation; but that does not describe performative verbs accurately.

> If I say, *"I apologise"*, **by** saying *"apologise"*, I make my apology.

The word *by* is essential: it tells us that saying "I apologise" is the *cause* of the action. Or, better: saying it *is* the action; saying it *constitutes* the action.

When you say, *I run*, your utterance alone does not make you run. Running and saying *I run* are not the same action (saying *I run* is an action of saying, whereas running a marathon is not an action of saying). That is why *run* is no performative verb in this context.

If you can say *I run* without actually running, then it is no performative verb. This is the 'negative' test, which is quite reliable. You can't say *I promise* without actually making a promise, which is why *promise* is a performative verb: the utterance and the action cannot be separated, because they are one.*

---

*) You can use verbs that are normally performative in a weird way, such that they are no longer performative; but that is exceptional.

Comment: Great, the concept of "the cause of the action" is new, but why don't other sites mention it. Could you give us some reference sources for your answer?

Comment: Austin's original example of performatives was "I do" in a wedding ceremony. *In that particular context*,  doing and saying are the same thing.

Comment: @Tom: Well, it's common knowledge. I don't have a specific source for using the word *cause*. But anyway, a more advanced (and better) way of describing it is by saying that it *is* the action, as I mention immediately afterwards. If you look at Wikipaedia, it says: *performative utterances are sentences which are ... changing the social reality they are describing* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_utterance). *Changing reality* = causing reality to change.

Comment: is "give" or "do" a Performative Verb? in this wiki link (http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Performative) "**I give and bequeath my watch to my brother**". Also, is it ok to say "**I give you 5 dollars**". What are the difference between "**I give you 5 dollars**" & "**I'll give you 5 dollars**"?

Comment: Is "**stress**" a performative verb? Can I say "**I really stress out**"?

Comment: @Tom: No. Performative verbs are all verbs of communication, like _state, promise, beg, request, order, christen,_ etc. Does saying _I really stress out_ make the speaker stress out? One test is the use of _hereby_: _I hereby promise to pay; I hereby request permission_,  but not *_I hereby stress out_

Comment: A really nice explanation. +1 for the example of "promise"

Comment: @Tom Uttering the phrase "I give you five dollars" doesn't cause a transfer any money; the money isn't "given" until you hand over cash, or write a check, etc. So "give" is not performative. But uttering the phrase "I promise you five dollars" does cause a promise to be made; the promise is made by virtue of saying the words "I promise". That makes "promise" performative. The speech IS the act; the act IS the speech.

Comment: @Cerberus I've found the term *speech act* (which as I understand is synonymous) to be a bit more accessible than *performative utterance*.

Comment: @chrylis: Mmm but isn't the term *speech act* usually taken to have a much broader scope? That is, I believe it includes far more than the narrow sense of *performative utterance*?

Comment: With reference to [this more recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/459977/what-is-the-word-the-means-there-is-a-difference-in-meaning-of-the-same-words-wh/459979?noredirect=1#comment1108706_459977), perhaps my duplicate closevote there (citing this question here) might carry more weight if you were to include some reference to the terminology [***illocutionary acts**.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illocutionary_act)